# The group defined by Gauss's definition of composition of forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

In article 242 of *Disquisitiones*, Gauss investigates the properties of the direct composition of two forms of the same discriminant.  In this case, he gives a "natural" choice for such a composition.  Denoting this composition by $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$ (so skipping the extra "2" in Gauss's way of writing forms), Gauss notes that $A$ is determined by his definition, while $B$ is determined modulo $2A$.  Once $A$ and $B$ are determined, $C$ is determined because the determinant is fixed.

This can be rephrased by saying that Gauss composition is well defined on the equivalence classes of forms under the action of the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2 (\mathbb{Z})$ consisting of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & m\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. These classes then form a countably generated infinite Abelian group.

This group was studied for positive discriminant by Lenstra in his 1980 paper "On the calculation of regulators and class numbers of quadratic fields".  Among other things, he embeds the group in a topological group which he notes is a subquotient of the idèle group of the corresponding quadratic field.  Schoof later pointed out in "Computing Arakelov class groups" that Lenstra's topological group is essentially the Arakelov class group of the field.

My question is, was this group studied in its own right after Gauss?  Or did all number theorists of the 19th and early 20th centuries study only the class group, and later the group of fractional ideals?

Comment: I don't know. This might be a good question for the history of math site (or is it history of science?).

Comment: hsm.stackexchange.com, History of Science and Mathematics.

Comment: So, have you tried hsm?

Comment: No, but I like the suggestion.  I googled and found that most people said it is inappropriate to cross-post rather than migrate.  I was planning to a wait a little while before requesting to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

It is of course difficult to answer such questions unless the answer is positive, which I am afraid it isn't. Certainly the first two generations after Gauss who were familiar with his composition (Dirichlet, Jacobi, Eisenstein, Kummer, Pepin, Dedekind) did not study this group. After Hilbert's Zahlbericht composition was rarely used, and in fact most number theorists preferred Dedekind's language of modules. As far as I am aware, it was indeed Lenstra who pointed out the connection between Gauss's theory of composition and the idea of Shanks' infrastructure.